# EF Core pass TEntity for dbContext to do Update or Add

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

Using EF Core, I have 10 methods that basically do the same thing. Update or Add and then SaveChanges()

i.e.

```
  public void UpdateUser(User model)
    {
        if(... some condition.. to determine to add or update)
        {
            db.Update(model);
            db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        else
        {        
           db.User.Add(model);
        } 
        db.SaveChanges(); 
    }

  public void UpdateCompany(Company model)
       {
        if(... some condition.. to determine to add or update)
        {
            db.Update(model);
            db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        else
        {        
           db.Company.Add(model);
        } 
        db.SaveChanges(); 
    }
```

possible to create one method and just pass Entity want to update or add?

Answer (score 0):

the real difference between `Update` and `Add` is `PrimaryKey` values. when u try to `Update` a data which is contains null `PrimaryKey` its not gonna update the data , its gonna add that data. u can controll the `model` to learn is it update or not . if `PrimaryKey` is null it can add that data. if the `PrimaryKey` is not null u can `Update` the data :

```
    public void UpdateOrAdd(Company model)
    {
        if(model.CompanyID !=0) //The primary key
        {
            db.Update(model);
            db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        else
        {        
           db.Company.Add(model);
        } 
        db.SaveChanges(); 
    }
```

EF creates a `PrimaryKey` value after the `db.SaveChanges();` method.

i suggest u to put try catch on that  `db.SaveChanges();` method as a last thing. u can get the error message and show it to yourself with a SweetAlert, u can give a correct message is that action %100 success or not.

Comment: I understand the difference between Update and Add. My question, I have many methods that basically does same thing.. update or add entity, so for example User table, Company table.. Is there away to avoid creating many same methods and just have one and pass entity i want to update/add ?

Comment: i never tried that, sorry. i will search that

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic method.  If you need access to the DbSet for an entity use `db.Set<TEntity>()` instead of the declared DbSet properties, `db.Users` or `db.Comanies`.

```
    public void Update<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity: class
    {

        if (1==1 /*whatever*/)
        {
            db.Update(entity);
        }
        else
        {
            db.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```